# sql connection error 000webhost

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, database-connection

I am using 000 webhost to store a sql database.
Every time I want to connect to it I recieve this error message

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /storage/h10/804/1186804/public_html/Handy_Help_PHP_files/conexiune.php on line 7
Connection failed: Connection refused
```

This is the php I use to connect

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "id1186804_admin";
$password = "12345";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Can somebody help me to find the error?

Comment: Take the port out of the server name. 3306 is default, so it's not needed, and that's not where it would go anyway.

Comment: @aynber thank you, it works

Answer (score 0):

with mysqli need add database name too

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "id1186804_admin";
$password = "12345";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$yourdbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

such:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: That doesn't address the connection refused error, and the database can be selected after the connection.

Comment: Thank you sir, I also changed the servername to localhost, and how everithing ia working perfectly. Thank you once again.

Comment: i am glad for you

Answer (score 0):

Remove port from host parameter and put in this order:

mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,**port**,socket);